# Remove Spring default metrics data

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, metrics

Is there any way I can remove Spring default metrics data? I did not find any way to do this in [Spring metrics documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html).

[Spring endpoints documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) does provide a way to disable the metrics endpoint, but I don't want to disable the endpoint, I just want to remove the default metrics data. Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Endpoints can be customized using Spring properties. You can change if an endpoint is enabled, if it is considered sensitive and even its id.

For example, here is an application.properties that changes the sensitivity and id of the beans endpoint and also enables shutdown.
(https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html)
endpoints.beans.id=springbeans
endpoints.beans.sensitive=false
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true

Comment: You should put it in "application.properties" file. create if there no next line: endpoints.metrics=false

Comment: @PetroGordiyevich Hi Petro. I don't want to disable the endpoint, I just want to disable the default metrics data.

Comment: Check this link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-dropwizard-metrics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a different solution. I first disabled the metrics endpoint using `endpoints.metrics.enabled:false`. Then I created a rest api for `/metrics`.

Answer (score 1):

[Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-metric-writers)

Try to set the following flag in `application.properties`:

```
spring.metrics.export.enabled=false
```